# Flask redirect to randomly named folder

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a small app that will (eventually):

Upload a file + process it with a background analysis tool + spit it back out to the user that uploaded it. I'm trying to put each file into a randomly generated folder name to keep things categorized a bit.

To start with, I'm getting the upload redirects working, and they're almost there but I can't seem to get flask to redirect to a randomly generated folder name, even though it exists and the file the user has uploaded is in it.

Here's how I'm accomplishing this...

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        foldername = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='file', dir='uploads')
        file.save(os.path.join(foldername, filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', foldername=foldername, filename=filename))
    else:
        return '<h3>Invalid File, PDF or image only.</h3>'

@app.route('/<foldername>/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(foldername, filename):
    return send_from_directory(filename)
```

On the redirect, the file is in the right place, and the folder is in the right place, and the browser is headed to the right place, but flask 404s it...

```
192.168.1.69 - - [29/Jan/2017 22:32:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.69 - - [29/Jan/2017 22:32:25] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
192.168.1.69 - - [29/Jan/2017 22:32:25] "GET /uploads/file0wr5ug4y/Screen_Shot_2017-01-25_at_11.23.48_AM.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: You are accessing `/uploads/fileXXXXX` but your mapped url in flask is simply `/foldername/filename` which seems to suggest the right link is `/file0wr5ug4y/Screen_Shot_2017-01-25_at_11.23.48_AM.png` (note: without the `/uploads`). Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: The docs say that the returned value from tempfile.mkdtemp() is the absolute path, and my testing confirms that as accurate. The prefix is already in the variable value, if I add the prefix to the route, I get a double prefix in the URL.


192.168.1.69 - - [29/Jan/2017 22:52:30] "GET /uploads/uploads/filef8gs8rdb/Screen_Shot_2017-01-25_at_10.44.53_AM.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Why not `@app.route('/uploads/<foldername>/<filename>')`, and then `return send_from_directory('/uploads/{}/{}'.format(foldername, filename))`

Comment: In trying random things it seems that I may have answered this one with error traces...

"TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument."

Due to that, even though the url appears to be fine, url_for() will only spit out a single position, so if I'm reading that correctly it cannot possibly redirect to a path with a foldername + filename separately?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the last comment to the first string of replies, trial and error figured it out.

The foldername must be passed to the send_from_directory function as well, and more importantly must be prefixed with 'path:' to allow the filename variable value to be a path.

So the final route looks like...

```
@app.route('/<foldername>/<path:filename>')
def uploaded_file(foldername, filename):
    return send_from_directory(foldername, filename)
```